# mysql man pages options apearing with question marks

Tags: mysql, centos, man

In the man pages of mysql(mysql, mysqladmin) the options appears with '?' instead of '-a, -p, etc', other commands are not affected

Centos 6.4 min install

Comment: How did you connect to the server? With what terminal? What are your locale settings?

Comment: i connect through ssh everytime I connect it gives me the  warning: "setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory"

Comment: What is the output of the `locale` command, when run on your _local_ machine (not the remote server)?

Comment: LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=

Comment: now locale in the server: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

Answer (score 2):

Your locale isn't set correctly on your local workstation. It's defaulting to the "C" locale.

Since you didn't provide any details about the workstation, it's hard to give specific advice on correcting it, though if you're using a GUI you can usually set the locale on the login screen by choosing a language (other than "Default").

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtBjQ.png]

It's also possible your workstation doesn't have any locales installed at all, which is usually how systems end up using the default "C" locale. Consult your operating system distribution's documentation to learn how to install locales.